# Django-admin dynamically filter ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = Models.ForeignKey(Foo)
class Last(models.Model):
    bar = Models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

When I want to create a new instance of Last , bar field in djando-admin contains all instances of Bar. How to filter it by relationship with Foo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_id_fields = ('bar',)` in your Admin class